# How to check whether specified select option label exists or not using Selenium IDE

Tags: firefox, select, selenium-ide, dropdown

I'm new to selenium and using Selenium IDE 2.9.1 for Firefox. I can toggle hide or show the specific option in dropdown list, so I need check whether specified select option label exists or not.

verifyselectOptions or assertselectOptions will return all options, but the options are not fixed and very big, so this is not a good choice. As the specified option are not selected, so method like verifyselectedlabel doesn't work for me.

Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance.